# What tax forms should REIT owners expect to receive?

Tags: united-states, taxes, reit

In the United States, an MLP generates a yearly K-1 form. Do REITs generate any special year end tax form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

REITs pay dividends and send form 1099-DIV (either directly or through the brokers, depending on how you invested). Here's the quote from the [Vanguard FAQ](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/help/FAQTaxesContent.jsp#1099REIT):

> Shareholders who have held the REIT Index Fund during the year
>   shouldn't file federal or state income tax returns until they receive
>   their Form 1099-DIV for REIT Index Fund.

You can also look at [the relevant article from Morningstar](http://news.morningstar.com/classroom2/course.asp?docId=145579&page=2&CN=).

Answer (score 0):

Terrible answer.  The question was about REITs, not index funds.  If you hold MLPs individually, you receive a K-1.  If you MLPs in a fund, you receive a 1099 - the fund gets the K-1.

Comment: See the link in my answer. It is not terrible and you're wrong. REITs are **not** MLPs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/87387)